# How to select all the experiences from a specific user profile in Node and Mongoose from embedded schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building an API in NodeJS Express and MongoDB using Mongoose.
I created a Profile model that embeds the Experience schema. 
Like:

```
{
    "_id": "5e26ff6d5be84a3aeeb2f7bb",
    "username": "some"
    <fields of the profile>
    "experience": [
        {
            "image": "",
            "createdAt": "2020-01-21T13:41:01.873Z",
            "updatedAt": "2020-01-21T13:41:01.873Z",
            "_id": "5e26ff6d5be84a3aeeb2f7bc",
            "title": "Senior Dev",
            "role": "Dev",
            "company": "ArosaDev",
            "startDate": "2018-12-03T23:00:00.000Z",
            "endDate": null,
            "description": "",
            "area": ""
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2020-01-21T13:41:01.874Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-01-21T13:41:01.874Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

The problem is I have to create an endpoint GET which gets for one profile all the experiences.

```
experienceRouter.get("/:username", async(req, res) => {

    console.log(req.params.username);

    const experiences = await Profiles.findOne({"username":req.params.username} ??? );

    res.send(experiences);
});
```

I know I should select the embedded field experience and get back all the experiences but I don't know how should I do with Mongoose in my route.

I don't know what comes next after I select the username and how I can select the all experience for the username I'm requested.

I'm new to this and cannot find any good references explaining to me that for good.

I will appreciate an example of how a route like this should be done.

My model:

```
// Profile Schema model
// Embedded we have the Experience as []
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { isEmail } = require("validator");


const experienceSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

        title: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        role: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        company: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        startDate: {
            type: Date,
            required: true
        },
        endDate: {
            type: Date
        },
        description: {
            type: String
        },
        area: {
            type: String
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
            required: false
        },

        updatedAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now,
            required: false
        },

        image: {
            type: String,
            required: false,
            default: "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
        }

})



const profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    surname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        validate: {
            validator: string => isEmail(string),
            message: "Provided email is invalid"
        }
    },

    bio: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    area: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    imageUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        default: "https://via.placeholder.com/150"
    },

    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },

    experience: [
        experienceSchema
    ],

    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: false
    },

    updatedAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: false
    }
});

const collectionName = "profiles";
const Profile = mongoose.model(collectionName, profileSchema);

module.exports = Profile;
```

Comment: DO you want to reference `experience` schema with `profiles`? and want to get all experiences of specific user?

Comment: I have to use the embedded design way as I showed in my model and my goal is that I want to get a profile by username and get its experiences only.
Example of output:
{_id .. username ... expereince[experiences]} so I see all the experiences for that one profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your code with below

You can mention your fields which you need in the second argument of function this is called projection [as mentioned](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/)

So for including of fields use `1` and for excluding fields use `0`

```
experienceRouter.get("/:username", async(req, res) => {

    console.log(req.params.username);

    const profile = await Profiles.findOne({"username":req.params.username},{experience:1 ,username:1, _id:0}).lean();

    res.send(profile);
});
```

Comment: Is this get all the experiences I have in the []?

Comment: @Jakub yes, it will fetch all data which is present in ```experience``` key

Comment: And if I want to add just before the result the username I requested like
{username: Jakub, experience: []} and a count also?  :)

Comment: you can fetch any field which is mentioned in your schema like username just add ```username:1```   and count of which field you want?

Comment: Sorry I'm new in this can you correct me please:
const profile = await Profiles.findOne(
        { username: req.params.username },
        { "username":1},
        { "experience": 2, _id: 0 }
    ).lean();

Comment: no problem @Jakub edited my answer. give it  +1 if it helped you :)

Comment: I did but error
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Projection cannot have a mix of inclusion and exclusion.

Comment: may you can help me with this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59859173/how-to-populate-in-nodejs-and-mongoose-a-post-which-need-to-be-referred-to-a-use @p u